# expose_decorated is not working with posts variable. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper, decent-exposure

I try to use draper, decent_exposure and decent_decoration gems in my project, but something is not working correctly. It's strange, because I just copied this code from antoher project.

my controller is:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  expose_decorated(:post)
  expose_decorated(:posts)

  def create
    if post.save
      redirect_to post_path(post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to post_path(post)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
    end

end
```

and here is index view

```
%h1 Blog

- posts.each do |post|
  %p= post.title
  %p= post.content
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `map' for #<Post:0x007f7df88dcca0>
Did you mean?  tap
```

Comment: If I use only decent_exposure with code `expose :posts, -> {Post.all}` it works correctly, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't work, because I was using version 3.0.0 of decent_exposure while decent_decoration is compatible with version >= 2.0.

I changed the version of decent_exposure to 2.3 and it works as it should.